# format a Microsoft JSON date in JavaScript original format

Tags: asp.net, ajax

i am using below function to convert my json date /Date(1450314910930)/

```
function jsonDateConvert(MyDate_String_Value)
    {
        var value = new Date
        (
             parseInt(MyDate_String_Value.replace(/(^.*\()|([+-].*$)/g, ''))
        );
        var dat = value.getMonth() +
                                 1 +
                               "/" +
                   value.getDate() +
                               "/" +
               value.getFullYear();
        return dat;
    }
```

My original date in database is 12/16/2015 but above function gives me +1 day ahead like 12/17/2015 please help me to get original date

Comment: I'm guessing the days and months are reversed since you add 1 to the getMonth(). Check your localization and the format of `MyDate_String_Value`

Comment: I seen that my jsonSerializer.Serialize automatically converted EST to IST time formate And i see the result while convert it in mm/dd/yyyy formate i looks like value = Thu Dec 17 2015 06:45:10 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```js
function jsonDateConvert(MyDate_String_Value)
{
    var d=new Date(MyDate_String_Value);
    var dat = d.getMonth() +1 +"/" + d.getDate() +"/" +d.getFullYear();
        
    document.getElementById("date_input").value = dat;
}

jsonDateConvert("12/16/2015")
```

```html
<input type="text" id="date_input"  />
```